# How to authenticate user ? (Android/Java/Symfony)

Tags: java, android, security, symfony

I'm developping an Android App that need authentication. However, there an existing web application (using Symfony) with accounts, and I have to reuse the same accounts to authenticate my users.

In the DB, I have the basicals : username, salt, encryptedPassword, encryption_type(sha1)...

The problem is that I don't know how to authenticate my users, by using these informations.

If someone can help me solving this...

Many thanks!

Comment: Search on _Google_ for that.

Comment: Usually method login(username, password) should be implemented. Other method throw exception, when they're run outside session (i.e. without prior logging in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeded in doing that ! I've analysed the way Symfony check the password thanks to the PHP class "PluginsfGuardUser".

```
public final boolean authenticate(User user)

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA1);

    byte[] saltPassword = (user.getSalt() + user.getPassword()).getBytes();
    byte[] encryptedPassword = md.digest(saltPassword);

    String pass = byteArrayToHexString(encryptedPassword);

    if (pass.equals(user.getDbPassword())) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] array) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result
                += Integer.toString((array[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the encryption algorithm you would do something like this:

```
public final boolean authenticate(String attemptedPassword, byte[] encryptedPassword, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
  String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
  int derivedKeyLength = 160;
  int iterations = 20000;
  KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, derivedKeyLength);
  SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);

  byte[] encryptedPassword = f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();

  return Arrays.equals(encryptedPassword, encryptedAttemptedPassword);
}
```

You need to know which settings were used to generate the encrypted passwords in your database.

Comment: Do the derivedKeyLenght and iterations are part of the settings ?

Comment: Yes they are. You have to use the same settings on server and on client side.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I'll try.